# How to alternate turns in a turtle based game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
print("Finished Loading!") 
print("x's turn")
xturn = True


if xturn == True:
    usl.onclick(x1)
    usc.onclick(yo)
    usr.onclick(x3)
    csr.onclick(x4)
    csl.onclick(x5)
    cs.onclick(x6)
    dsl.onclick(x7)
    dsc.onclick(x8)
    dsr.onclick(x9)
else:
    print("o's Turn")
    usl.onclick(o1)
```

I am creating A Tic-tac-toe game for a class and have the playing mechanics finished(When someone clicks a box makes an x/o) but I am now struggling with turns. The excerpt above is what I would mostly likely need to motify.  I was wondering if anyone knew how you can use events in turtle graphics to change a varible or if anyone knows a good system for alternating turns that would be Great!

Answer (score 0):

I took this question as a challenge to write as little turtle code as possible to implement a working tic-tac-toe interface.  The code below alternates between X's & O's turns and won't let a square be reused.  It doesn't attempt to score the game nor itself play the game, it's just a minimal interface to build your smarts onto:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

UNIT_SIZE = 80
HALF_GRID_SIZE = 3 * UNIT_SIZE / 2
FONT_SIZE = 48  # adjust to taste

x_turn = True

def choosen(turtle):
    global x_turn

    turtle.onclick(None)  # taken so no longer responds

    x, y = turtle.position()
    magic_marker.goto(x, y - FONT_SIZE / 2)
    magic_marker.write("X" if x_turn else "O", font=("Arial", FONT_SIZE, "bold"), align="center")

    x_turn = not x_turn

magic_marker = Turtle(visible=False)
magic_marker.speed("fastest")
magic_marker.penup()

for row in range(-UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE + 1, UNIT_SIZE):
    if row >= 0:
        magic_marker.goto(-HALF_GRID_SIZE, row - UNIT_SIZE / 2)
        magic_marker.pendown()
        magic_marker.setx(HALF_GRID_SIZE)
        magic_marker.penup()

    for column in range(-UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE + 1, UNIT_SIZE):

        if column >= 0:
            magic_marker.goto(column - UNIT_SIZE / 2, -HALF_GRID_SIZE)
            magic_marker.pendown()
            magic_marker.sety(HALF_GRID_SIZE)
            magic_marker.penup()

        turtle = Turtle(shape="square", visible=False)
        turtle.shapesize(0.8 * (UNIT_SIZE / 20))  # 0.8 = a safety margin
        turtle.color("white")
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(column, row)
        turtle.showturtle()  # still white on white but not clickable if not visible

        turtle.onclick(lambda x, y, t = turtle: choosen(t))

screen = Screen()
screen.mainloop()
```

It uses click events and turns control over to the main loop so other events can also be active.

[image]